# Add sequential subdirectories to sequential directories

Tags: bash, loops, subdirectory, sequential

I need to add subdirectories to multiple directories. I have a structure so far like dog[11-20]-[A-L] and I would like a subdirectory that looks like dog[11-20]-[A-L]-1. I would like to try to accomplish this with as few commands as possible. My efforts with the find command and piping have not worked. So for example dog11-A i would like a subdirectory named dog11-A-1 and for dog15-B i would like a subdirectory dog15-B-1.

Comment: Are you trying to create *all* of those directories? Or just create a `-1`-suffixed directory for every existing (non-suffixed) directory?

Comment: Im trying to create all of them.

Answer (score 3):

```
for d in dog{11..20}-{A..L}; do
    mkdir -p "$d/$d-1"
done
```

This will create the parent as well, if necessary. You can also build up the required names in an array and pass that to a single call to `mkdir`. If

```
for d in {11..20}; do
    for suffix in {A..L}; do
        base=dog$d-$suffix
        dirs+=("$base/$base-1")
    done
done
mkdir -p "${dirs[@]}"
```

If that gives you a "too many arguments" error, you can make a larger number of aggregated calls:

```
for d in {11..20}; do
    dirs=()
    for suffix in {A..L}; do
        base=dog$d-$suffix
        dirs+=("$base/$base-1")
    done
    mkdir -p "${dirs[@]}"
done
```

Comment: Ill check and confirm! Can i add the same group of files to these subdirectories, too?

Comment: If you are copying a group of files into each subdirectory, you'll have to use the first option (one call to `mkdir` per directory); I'm not away of any commands that can copy a set of files to multiple locations at once.

Comment: ISSUE: mkdir: cannot create directory `/-1': Permission deniedmkdir: cannot create directory `/-1': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory `/-1': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory `/-1': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory `/-1': Permission denied
./sdc.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `for'
./sdc.sh: line 8: `     for suffix in {A..L}; do'

Comment: advice? i wrote the script by combining the top portion of code and the bottom

Comment: I just used the bottom portion and im getting a line 4 syntax error near 'for' and 'for suffix in {A..L}; do'